# ImageMagick RGB to CMYK conversion results in very dark images

Tags: imagemagick-convert

On one server (running ImageMagick 6.7.7) when I convert RGB to CMYK the resulting images are fine, but when I run the same command on another server (sadly the production one!) I get much darker images.

I've tried removing colour profiles etc. which sadly doesn't seem to work.

I think I must have done some tweaking to the server which is working correctly. Has anyone done anything similar to get this type of conversion to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, ImageMagick 6.7.7-7 works fine but ImageMagick 6.8.6-9 doesn't.

I founded a issue called [ImageMagick 6.7.6.4 produces all black images due to -colorspace RGB argument](https://github.com/flourishlib/flourish-classes/issues/38) on GitHub and all works fine now (I don't have this version but it works).

Summarizing: The solution is change RGB to sRGB.

Sorry for my english.